# Does the existence proof of $\mu$-completion require choice?

Tags: measure-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $\mathfrak{M}^*=\{E\subset X|\exists A,B\in\mathfrak{M} \text{ such that} A\subset E \subset B \text{ and} \mu(B\setminus A)=0\}$.

How do i show that $\mathfrak{M}^*$ is closed under countable union?

Following is what i tried:

Let $\{E_n\}$ be a sequence of elements of $\mathfrak{M}^*$.

Define $I_n=\{(A,B)\in\mathfrak{M}\times\mathfrak{M}|A\subset E_n\subset B \text{ and} \mu(B\setminus A)=0\}$

Again, define $P_n=\{A\in \mathfrak{M}|(A,B)\in I_n\}$ and $Q_n=\{B\in \mathfrak{M}|(A,B)\in I_n\}$.

Then, $\bigcup P_n$ and $\bigcap Q_n$ are elements of $\mathfrak{M}^*$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

It can be shown that [If $C$ is measurable and $\bigcup P_n\subset C \subset E_n$, then $C\subset \bigcup P_n$], which means that there is no measurable set between $\bigcup P_n$ and $E_n$.

Is this $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are in $\mathfrak{M}$?

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether $\bigcup P_n,\bigcap Q_n$ are in $\frak M$?

Comment: @Asaf only if it is true, but it seems false now. My main interest is whether there exists a $\mu$-completion in ZF :)

Comment: You mean a $\sigma$-additive completion.

Comment: @Asaf Yes. I want to show that $\mathfrak{M}^*$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. So far, I have shown that $X\in\mathfrak{M}^*$ and [$E\in\mathfrak{M}^*\Rightarrow X\setminus E\in\mathfrak{M}^*$]

Comment: It is trivially an algebra. Yes.

Comment: My first comment, by the way, refers to the last line in your question.

Comment: @Asaf How can i prove that $\mathfrak{M}^*$ is a $\sigma$-algebra without choice? Would you please write that as an answer?

Comment: I didn't write $\sigma$-algebra. I wrote **algebra**, and for a good reason too. If I knew how to prove that this is a $\sigma$-algebra I'd have written that already. I'm currently trying to construct a counterexample.

Comment: @Asaf I got it. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{N}=\{B\in\mathfrak{M}:\mu(B)=0\}$ and $\mathcal{N^*}=\{N\subseteq X:\textrm{ there is a }B\in\mathcal{N}\textrm{ such that }N\subseteq B\}.$ Then you can show that $\mathfrak{M}^*=\{M\cup N:M\in\mathfrak{M}\textrm{ and }N\in\mathcal{N}\}$ without choice. This should simplify the problem to whether one can show without choice that $\mathcal{N}^*$ is a $\sigma$-ideal.

Comment: @Michael: I'm not sure how that simplifies the problem. Given $E_n$ you would like to have written them as $A_n\cup N_n$ but that would be a choice just as well. Actually using the notation Katlus uses in the question seems clearer to me. **Katlus:** I'm still working on that counterexample.